# "The system is running in low-graphics mode" while installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, graphics, syslinux

I get "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error while I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 to my laptop.
I have Nvidia GT940MX and Intel HD Graphics.
Note that I am using a multiboot USB drive, and here are some configs:

```
CONFIG /multiboot/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/isolinux/isolinux.cfg /multiboot/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/isolinux
```

ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64/isolinux/isolinux.cfg:

```
# D-I config version 2.0
# search path for the c32 support libraries (libcom32, libutil etc.)
path 
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

menu.cfg:

```
menu hshift 13
menu width 49
menu margin 8

menu title Installer boot menu
include stdmenu.cfg
include txt.cfg
include gtk.cfg
menu begin advanced
    menu title Advanced options
    include stdmenu.cfg
    label mainmenu
        menu label ^Back..
        menu exit
    include adtxt.cfg
    include adgtk.cfg
menu end
label help
    menu label ^Help
    text help
   Display help screens; type 'menu' at boot prompt to return to this menu
    endtext
    config prompt.cfg
```

I don't see any menu before I get the error. Also I am trying to access TTY console but it wants login, I've tried ubuntu:ubuntu root:root [blank]:[blank] root:[blank] root:toor but none worked.
What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Where should I put this? :P

Comment: Yea sorry :D I just didn't want to do something wrong, thank you so much!